# Rails turns "CONTENT_TYPE" into "HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE". How to force Rails not to do this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, http-headers

I am using a gem called [JSNOAPI-resources](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources) to build an API. 
This API requires every request to have "application/vnd.api+json" as value of the "CONTENT_TYPE" header.

Problems that I have is that whenever I set "CONTENT_TYPE" at the client side, Rails will turn it into "HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"(https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/headers.rb). Therefore, the JSONAPI-resources gem will error out because the CONTENT_TYPE is not correctly set.

How do I set the CONTENT_TYPE at client side for Rails to receive it as CONTENT_TYPE instead of prepending it with "HTTP_"?

Thank you very much!